# how to remove one of the duplicate records?

Tags: mysql

Having the following table

```
mysql> desc customer;
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id               | char(36)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| firstname        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date_entered     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date_modified    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| modified_user_id | char(36)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| created_by       | char(36)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| description      | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| deleted          | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| assigned_user_id | char(36)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lastname         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| email            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pc               | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| country          | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| telephone        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dob              | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And a set of duplicate records similar to the following

```
mysql> SELECT email, COUNT(*) count FROM customer GROUP BY email HAVING count > 1 ORDER BY count DESC limit 10;
+-----------------------------+-------+
| email                       | count |
+-----------------------------+-------+
| ada.won@gmail.com           |     2 |
| chris.redfil@gmail.com      |     2 |
| rebecac@abcinstitute.edu    |     2 |
| leonken@gmail.com           |     2 |
| albert.wesker.umb@earth.net |     2 |
| tren.seve@gmail.com         |     2 |
| a123aa@gmail.com            |     2 |
| john.log@gmail.com          |     2 |
| example.sam@gmail.com       |     2 |
| racooon.city@gmail.com      |     2 |
+-----------------------------+-------+
```

For example

```
mysql> select firstname, lastname, pc, country, telephone, dob, date_entered, deleted from customer where email = "tren.seve@gmail.com"
+-----------------------+----------+------------+---------+----------+-----------+----------+------+---------+
| firstname             | lastname | pc         | country | telephone | dob  | date_entered        | deleted |
+-----------------------+----------+------------+---------+-----------+------+---------------------+---------+
| ANTONIO CHICA GALLEGO |          |            | ES      | NULL      | NULL | 2023-03-24 21:50:15 |       0 |
| ANTONIO CHICA GALLEGO |          |            | ES      |           | NULL | 2023-04-04 09:42:11 |       0 |
+-----------------------+----------+------------+---------+-----------+-----------+----------+------+--------+
```

I need to remove one of these duplicate records, so that only one remains of each duplicate record

How to remove one of the duplicate records?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM customer 
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT id FROM customer 
        WHERE email = "tren.seve@gmail.com"
        ORDER BY date_entered DESC 
        LIMIT 1
    ) temp
)
AND email = "tren.seve@gmail.com";
```

- deleting all duplicate records for email `"tren.seve@gmail.com"` except latest date_entered
- modify based on requirements

edit:

```
DELETE c1
FROM customer c1, customer c2
WHERE c1.email = c2.email
AND c1.date_entered < c2.date_entered
```

- deletes one of the duplicate records for each email address except latest date_entered
- detail: join the customer table with itself(creates alias c1, c2) -- compare email addresses and date_entered -- `WHERE` specifies (the records selected for deletion are those with the same email address + older date_entered) -- selecting c1 in `DELETE` removes the older record

Comment: Hello. thanks for answering. The query should work with every duplicate record. Because there are several thousand records

Comment: I have made an update to the answer, I hope this works for you. Ps(it's smart to take a backup of the table temporarily before running large delete statements)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this query

```
UPDATE customer c1 SET c1.deleted = 1
WHERE  EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM  (SELECT 1
              FROM   customer c2
              WHERE  c2.email = c1.email AND c2.id < c1.id) c3)
```

That means per each record, if there are existed other records that have the same `email` and smaller `id`, then update value of its `deleted` column to `1`.

This query will update value of `deleted` column of all records that have the same `email`, except the one will smallest `id`.

In case that you actually want to delete records, just replace `UPDATE` with `DELETE` statement.

Comment: Hello. thanks for answering. I try to understand your query. Could you explain it? Regarding the id, I should mention that the id is uuid, so I don't think comparing by id would work.

Comment: @Mario I've edited my answer to add more detail explanation. The comparison of `id` is just to keep the smallest `id` record remain unchanged. You could change it to `c2.id > c1.id`  if you want to keep the biggest `id`

Comment: @Mario Instead of using `id` column, you could also be able to use comparison on other column, like `date_entered` or `date_modified` for keeping the oldest/latest record.

Comment: When trying the query i get this message `You can't specify target table 'c1' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my query. I've forgot that MySQL is a little awkward with update or delete statements that uses the target table in a sub-query. We have to wrapped sub-query inside another select to make it work.

Comment: You could check the similar working sample query here: https://dbfiddle.uk/jZUTeTrd